# DBConcurrency Exception Occured While Updating Using Dataadapter

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to edit `DataTable` Filled by `NpgsqlDataAdapter`.
After calling `Fill()` method, I have only one row in `DataTable`. Then I changed value of one column only and tried to update as below.

[image]

Then I am getting this error:

> DBConcurrencyException occured

My code is:

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter getAllData = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT sn,
code,product, unitprice, quantity, InvoiceNo, Date FROM stocktable WHERE Code='" + product + "'
 ORDER BY EDate ASC", DatabaseConnectionpg);
DataTable ds1 = new DataTable();
ds1.Clear();
getAllData.Fill(ds1);

if (ds1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ds1.Rows[0]["Quantity"] = qty;// calculated value
}
ds1 = ds1.GetChanges();

NpgsqlCommandBuilder cb = new NpgsqlCommandBuilder(getAllData);
//getAllData.RowUpdating += (sender2, e2) => { e2.Command.Parameters.Clear(); };
//cb.SetAllValues = false;
getAllData.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
getAllData.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
getAllData.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
int x = getAllData.Update(ds1);
if (x > 0)
{
    ds1.AcceptChanges();
}
```

**EDIT:** I have three fields as primary keys and I am calling only two fields in select statement. Is it reason for `DBConcurrency` error? But I am able to update the table with same (three fields as primary key) parameters in SQL Server 2005.

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution and the solution is 
I created and used second DataAdapter to update data.
I used **getAllData**(NpgSqlDataAdapter) To fill table as

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter getAllData = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT 
code,product, unitprice, quantity, InvoiceNo, Date FROM stocktable WHERE Code='" + product + "'
 ORDER BY EDate ASC", DatabaseConnectionpg);
```

And Also created next Adapter to update as

```
NpgsqlDataAdapter updateadap= new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT sn, quantity FROM stocktable WHERE Code='" + product + "'
 ORDER BY EDate ASC", DatabaseConnectionpg);
NpgsqlCommandBuilder cb = new NpgsqlCommandBuilder(updateadap);
    //getAllData.RowUpdating += (sender2, e2) => { e2.Command.Parameters.Clear(); };
    //cb.SetAllValues = false;
    updateadap.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
    updateadap.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
    updateadap.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
    int x = updateadap.Update(ds1);
    if (x > 0)
    {
        ......
    }
```

**I tried alot and found that NpgsqlDataAdapter had problem with Column *Code*. When i ommited it then it worked. DataType of column code is varchar.** I don't know why this was happening. Anybody has idea about it?

Comment: can you please post the exact schema for table stocktable (you can do this by running '\d stocktable' in psql)? Also, what is the type of variable qty? Note that there can only be one primary key in a PG table, not three (although you can have as many indices as you want)

Comment: One more thing that would help is the result of the query you're making (i.e. the exact values)

Answer (score 6):

This is because `DataAdapter` uses [`Optimistic Concurrency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz(v=vs.110).aspx) by default. This means that if you are trying to update a row that no longer exists in the database or changed, the update from the `DataAdapter` will fail with the exception above.

**Possible scenarios**:

- Between you selecting the data into the client and sending the
  update, another user is deleting or updating this row from his application.
- It can be that you are deleting the data from somewhere else in your application.

**For example**:

1. You fill the `DataTable` that will be used for the update.
2. Deletes the row with `Code = 1101` (for example) directly from the database, i.e. you do not use the `DataTable` here. This is emulating another user deleting the row with `Code = 1101` from another application. Or some other part in your code deleting the row with `Code = 1101`.
3. Selects out the row with `Code = 1101` from the `DataTable`, this is just to show that it is still there even though you have deleted it from the database itself.
4. Edits the `Quantity` column in the row with `Code = 1101` in the `DataTable`. This has to be done, otherwise the call to Update will ignore this row when updating.
5. Executes the update, this will throw the exception since you are trying to update a row that (no longer) exists in the database.

If you want to implement [`Last Writer Wins`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency), Add the following code:

```
cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

Also there is one more possible thing : if you have `Decimal`/`numeric` as columns in the DB they may cause this error even though the data looks the same. This is due to a decimal rounding error.

**An important note**:
You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).