# Edit razorview Entity Framework from view model: Error: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using an ASP.NET MVC Razor view and Entity Framework to do CRUD operations. I am using a ViewModel to save changes to the model. I also have file uploads as part of this. The `Create` function works fine, but the `Edit` is where I keep getting the error

> "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."

And I am not sure where the trouble is.

My code is as follows:

View model:

```
public class ModelNameVM
{
    public int? PinNumbers { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase SerialAttachment { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase CountryAttachment { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase OtherAttachment { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml:**

```
@model ModelName
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PinNumbers)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SerialAttachment, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryAttachment , new { type = "file" })
...
```

Controller:

```
//GET Edit
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ModelName data= db.entityname.Find(id); //

    if (data== null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(data);
}

//POST Edit
public ActionResult Edit(ModelNameVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    ModelName data = new ModelName
    {
        PinNumbers = model.PinNumbers
    };

    if (model.SerialAttachment != null && model.SerialAttachment.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.SerialAttachment.FileName);
        ..... 
        model.SerialAttachment.SaveAs(path);
        data.SerialAttachment = path
    }

    .... // repeat for CountryAttachment and OtherAttachment 
    db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("Index", db.entityname.ToList());
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558609/2946329

Comment: You have a `HiddenFor` for `Id` while you haven't included it in your `ViewModel`. Shouldn't you have a property like this `public int Id { get; set; }` ?

Comment: I added the Id (see edited code), now the edit changes are happening but the attachments are not being saved.

Comment: Setting `EntityState.Modified` only affects scalar properties of an entity, not navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold: Could you tell me what I need to correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like in your Edit Post Action you are retrieving the existing model/entity. You are passing back to the controller your ViewModel and not the actual model, so it seems like you are just creating a new one, so there would be nothing to update.

Instead of creating the new ModelName:

```
   ModelName data = new ModelName
{
    PinNumbers = model.PinNumbers
};
```

Change it to(you will need to add the id to the viewModel):

```
var data = db.entityname.Find(model.id);

if (data!= null)
{
   data.PinNumbers = model.PinNumbers
}
else {  return HttpNotFound(); }
```

Or since in your Edit Get Method you are returning the Model to the View, you could change your method signature from:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ModelNameVM model)
```

To:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ModelName model)
```