# Entity Framework vs. stored procedure conflict - Concurrency Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, concurrency

I'm very new to stored procedures so please bear with me. I will try to do my best to explain the issue I am having and can provide supplementary information as needed.

I am trying to manipulate a database using both Entity Framework and a stored procedure. Initially, I call the stored procedure to via a

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
```

Immediately after that, I call a method via Entity Framework that ends with a `DB.SaveChanges`. While the former executes without issue, once I reach `DB.SaveChanges` in the latter, I get a concurrency exception:

> Affected an unexpected number of rows...

I figure that there is a concurrency issue where both Entity Framework and the stored procedure are trying to access the DB but come into conflict but I haven't been able to find a similar issue and how to resolve this.

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558609/2946329

Comment: Is that stored procedure call inside a `using (var ctx = new DbContext())` construct? Since that stored procedure changes the database "behind" EF's back, you should **NOT** do this while an EF DbContext is active - run the stored procedure, and then make sure to create a **new** DbContext so that the new, changed data is read from the database ....

Comment: @marc_s the stored procedure is called via a context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand after setting context equal to the DB. Then the Entity Framework does a Get via a BaseQuery, updates a value and calls DB.SaveChanges at which point I get the exception. Should a new Context be created between the two calls? Is there a way for the stored procedure to "let it go"? I've also seen a recommendation to do a context.SaveChanges in/after the stored procedure.

Comment: @S.Akbari I took a look at the provided link and it seems to summarize the issue pretty well. I am a bit unclear about the recommendation however, what does cb refer to? I did not see the ConflictOption extension on either context or Db.

Answer (score 0):

What stored procedure do? does it insert or update something? It seems you insert, update or delete a row but zero row affected.

Comment: Hi Amir, the stored procedure does an update for one value and the Entity Framework updates another value. The exception occurs after the stored procedure finishes and the Entity Framework makes its changes and tries to save them via DB.SaveChanges.