# How do I fix the error "UpdateCommand has affected 0 of 1 expected entries."?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, devexpress

**Used by:**
 - MSAccess 2016.
 - Autoincrement "ID" is formed in the database table.
 - DevExpress.
 - gridControl.

After I add a new entry to "gridControl1" I need to add an "ID" from the database.

Scenario_1:
- User. Fills the required field; 
- User. Shifts focus to "gridControl1";
- The program. Adds a new entry to "gridControl1" - "Record_1";
- The program. Using the `Row_Changed` event, we add the entry "Record_1 "to the" database ";
- The program. Get ID "Record_1" from the database;
- The program. Updates the ID in the "DataTable" for the new entry "Record_1";

After executing the script "Scenario_1" the user tries to update any field of the new record.
Scenario_2:
- User. Changes the entry field "Record_1";
- User. Shifts focus to another entry;
- The program. Produces the error "UpdateCommand has affected 0 of 1 expected entries.";

How do I fix the error "UpdateCommand has affected 0 of 1 expected entries."?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**added**
State when an error occurs
[image]

```
   public void connect()
{
            string catBD = @"z:\vs\csharp\prb\718\01_pr\01_pr\01_pr\718.01.01.accdb";
            string conBD = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", catBD);

            connection = new OleDbConnection(conBD);
            connection.Open();          

            string query1 = "SELECT * FROM TableGrid_00";            

            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query1, connection);

            dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
                 cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
                 adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
                 adapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }

            adapter.Fill(dt);

            dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);
}


private void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
     adapter.Update(dt);

     string SearchByColumn = "ID is null";
     DataRow[] hasRows = dt.Select(SearchByColumn);
     if (hasRows.Length != 0)
     {
       string query = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TableGrid_00";

       OleDbCommand com;
       OleDbDataReader dataReader;
       com = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);


        dataReader = com.ExecuteReader();
        dataReader.Read();

        int resultQuery = dataReader.GetInt32(0);

        hasRows[0]["ID"] = resultQuery;

        dataReader.Close();
     }
     else
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558609/2946329

Comment: @S.Akbari I studied the link, but I don’t understand what I need to do.
If it is not difficult for you, could you tell me more in detail how I can solve my problem.
Added a picture to the question